# Hazelcast + spring security + distributed sessions = how to make it work?

Tags: spring, spring-security, distributed, hazelcast

Being inspired by http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/websessionreplication.html I decided to give it a try and use in my Spring MVC + Security application.

First issue I hit is - Hazelcast was complaining it can't find `sessionRegistry` bean. I solved it pretty quickly by adding following bean to spring-security context

```
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

But I hit next issue right away and still can't solve it. 
This is what happens:

1. Start tomcat (assuming app will be started as well)
2. Login to site - ok
3. Logout - ok (**CONCERN**: logged out ok, `JSESSIONID` and `REMEMBER_ME_TOKEN` cookies are cleared, but `hazelcast.sessionId` cookie is **NOT** cleared)
4. Restart tomcat
5. Navigate to index page
6. **ERROR**: Infinite redirects to `invalidSessionStrategy` happens

After some debugging I found several facts:

- it happens because inside `SessionManagementFilter#doFilter` check for `request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` returns `false`
- `JSESSIONID` and `hazelcast.sessionId` are different (which is I assume by design)
- looks like issue happens because of inconsistency between calls `request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` and `request.getSession()` - looks like if former returns `false`, then latter suppose to create new session - which doesn't happen

What I tried so far (and it didn't help):

- manually clear `hazelcast.sessionId` cookie using buildin spring security logout handler (no success, coockie appears again with same value)
- workaround https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3049 which is about sending `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` on logout. No effect was noticed
- tried ti use `JSESSIONID` as session id for hazelcast cookie name (in that case I can open ap only once, all subsequent requests result in infinite redirects to `invalid-session`)

So... Apparently it's not that simple as stated in official Hazelcast docs. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like I found how to fix that `infinite redirect to invalid session` issue. I'm not sure if it's shortcut or it's  100% right way to do so...

I created custom `InvalidSessionStrategyImpl` with following code:

```
@Override
public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request.getSession(false) instanceof HazelcastHttpSession) {
        HazelcastHttpSession hazelCastSession = (HazelcastHttpSession) request.getSession(false);
        hazelCastSession.invalidate();
    } else {
        request.getSession();
    }
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirecctTo);
}
```

p.s. In case you curious - right after that I hit another issue: excessive CPU consumption. Hazelcast eats 100% CPU. Completely unacceptable issue (especially for cloud deployment like Jelastic where you pay by resource usage).